# URI too long on post

Tags: uri, runtime-error, restsharp

I am making a request using the RestClient and RestRequest, after adding the parameters I get

Error:

```
Invalid URI: The URI string is too long.
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with it not posting the data correctly, Here is my code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "URL";
client.Authenticator =
    new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
            "KEY");
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
restRequest.AddParameter("domain",
            "DOMAIN", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
restRequest.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
restRequest.AddParameter("from", (string) sender["alias"] + "<email>");
restRequest.AddParameter("to", (string)recipient["alias"] + "<" + (string)recipient["email"] + ">");
restRequest.AddParameter("subject", subject);
restRequest.AddParameter("html", body);              
var result = client.Execute(restRequest);
if (result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     throw new Exception(result.ErrorMessage,new Exception(result.StatusCode + " - " + result.StatusDescription));
}
```

The body parameter could be very long as it is a HTML email.  What causes the above error?

Here is the request that the code makes using a shorter body so that it does send
http://pastebin.com/HgbBHVpC

Full stack trace including message trying to send http://pastebin.com/dRhXire6

Comment: you probably do a `get` request while you need to do a `post` request

Comment: I am doing a post, as you can see in the code the method is set to POST in the constructor for the RestRequest

Comment: Are you sure you add parameters to request body not the request query string?

Comment: according to the documentation from RestRequest this is the correct way. Here is an the summary for the AddParameter method 'Adds a HTTP parameter to the request (QueryString for GET, DELETE, OPTIONS and HEAD; Encoded form for POST and PUT)'

Comment: @MikeNorgate sorry overlooked that one.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492.aspx

looking at the doc it says 
The length of uriString exceeds 65519 characters

Comment: but in a post request the data shouldn't be put in the URI?

Comment: Do you have the full stack from the exception?

Comment: Try stepping thru the RestSharp code, you can downlaod it from https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp.  I tried to recreate it just now and the URI was created successfully using the body that you sent me.  Execute failed because of some security and it could be my test code isn't testing your code in the same way, but it did create the URI fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be `request.AddParameter(contentTyp, ContentItself, ParameterType.RequestBody);`
or `request.AddBody`. Also try to use something like fiddler to check what the actual request  (url\body) you send.

Comment: adding ParameterType.RequestBody gives a BadRequest error. Looking at the output from fiddler the content type is form encoded and the sent data is in the body not the query string

Comment: I have updated the question to include the request copied from Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known feature of RestSharp:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/restsharp/9b5bpK3gt9g